# Bootstrap accordion not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, touch

I have an accordion that look's like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">HEADER <i class="icon-plus-sign pull-right"></i></h4>
</div>
</a>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The panel should open when `#panel-heading` is pressed. It works just fine on pc but on touch devices it doesnt recognize the link. What can I do to fix this?

**Edit**: I assumed it didn't work on all touch devices but I just tried it on my Android phone and it works flawlessly. So it's only on the Ipad.